# What is the "resource" in imagecolorat()?

Tags: php, laravel, image

So consider the following, in **Laravel 5.7**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\Modules\Locations\Services\CreateMapService;
use ChristianEssl\LandmapGeneration\Struct\Color;
use App\Modules\Locations\Models\Location;

class SurfaceLocations extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $water = new Color(66, 129, 178);
        $land  = new Color(23, 132, 72);

        $createImage = new CreateMapService($land, $water, 500, 500, 'random_map');
        $createImage->generateMap('surface');

        $contents = Storage::disk('maps')->get('surface.png');

        $waterR = 66;
        $waterG = 129;
        $waterB = 178;

        for ($x = 0; $x <= 500; $x++) {
            for($y = 0; $y <= 500; $y++) {
                $rgb = imagecolorat($contents, $x, $y);

                $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                $b = $rgb & 0xFF;


                if ($r === $waterR && $g === $waterG && $b === $waterB) {
                    Location::create([
                        'x' => $x,
                        'y' => $y,
                        'is_water' => true
                    ]);
                } else {
                    Location::create([
                        'x' => $x,
                        'y' => $y,
                        'is_water' => false
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I create the map and save it, then I attempt to the contents of the image and then pass it to the imagecolor at, walking over every x,y position of the image looking to see if the water rgb matches the output rgb.

But I get the error:

> imagecolorat() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

So I looked up what this resource was and got the `imagecreatetruecolor()` function, but I am not sure how to use it with the image I created and saved.

Any ideas on how to use this function with an existing image? The docs, use the example of creating an image.

Comment: `$contents = imagecreatefrompng('surface.png');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix this line

```
$contents = Storage::disk('maps')->get('surface.png');
```

to be

```
$contents = imagecreatefromstring( Storage::disk('maps')->get('surface.png') );
```

and your code will work... because on way you did it you are putting in $contents content of file surface.png which is not image resource...

just please rename $contents to something more intuitive because that is image resource, not contents anymore